# how create custom tab bar like pinterest or piictu in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I need to create custom tab bar like pinterest or piictu ?
how to do that one,can any one help me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530493/how-to-create-pinterest-style-hiding-unhiding-nav-tab-bar

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend watching the WWDC 2012 "Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS" - this video will show you what you need to get started.

http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766